# Jquery UI Drag and Drop position of element jumps on first drop

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

So I have this project that im working on, and now im stuck :(

My problem is, when I drag and drop my item, I need to get/set its position relative to a container, not the entire body, so from what I understand I should use position(). I do this using

```
var pos=$(ui.helper).position();
objName = "#leaf"+counter++
$(objName).css({"left":pos.left,"top":pos.top});
```

Although this introduces a jump just after I drag in the div.

I had this working which would give me absolute left and right values using var pos=$(ui.helper).offset(); and setting my containers (#treeContainer) CSS to NOT CONTAIN "position:relative;" although this gave me  absolute values relative to the entire page!

Many thanks for any responses!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, remove the positioning CSS on the `#drag` objects. Those values carrying over to the destination object, and conflicting with your goals there. Alternatively, you can reset those values to 0 in the JS code.

```
#drag1 {
    width:74px;
    height:111px;
    float:right;
    background-color:#0F3;
}

#drag2 {
    width:74px;
    height:111px;
    float:right;
    background-color:#3C9;
}
```

Next, in the JS, you need to offset your `top` and `left` values with the values from the parent container by using subtraction.

```
      var pos = $(ui.helper).offset();
      var treePos = $('#treeContainer').offset();
      objName = "#leaf" + counter++;
      $(objName).css({"left": pos.left - treePos.left, "top": pos.top - treePos.top});
```

After these changes, it works as it should. See http://jsbin.com/exoqu3/6 for an example.

Comment: Hey thanks for the awesome reply, I have added in the code to my project but I am still getting the issue, but the jumps are alot smaller. I have updated my question with my project URL so you can see the whole picture, any ideas? Once again, thanks for the reply

Comment: It looks like the leaves are getting their position relative to their containing element, which is incorrect. Try this: instead of using .position(), use .offset() for both `pos` and `treePos`. See http://api.jquery.com/offset/

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
#drag1 {
  width:74px;
  height:111px;
  float:right;
    background-color:#0F3;
}
```

It has to do with your margins. Play around with them and I'm sure you'll get it.

Comment: hmm thanks for the reply but it has not completely fixed the issue. I dont understand why I can only get coordinates relative to the container if it has position:relative;, but if i keep position:relative; it makes the elements jump :(